# How to delete multiple substrings?

Tags: python, string

I'm working on a script that get some information from a PGN file, a format used to describe chess games. I'm trying to copy the moves of each game separately in another file.

But sometimes, there are comments, marked by '{' and '}' characters, and I would like to strip them from the string (I'm copying each line of the file into a string to make some adjustments before writing on the output file).

An example of a string in this format would be:

```
'1.e4 {some comment} c5 2.Nf3 d6 3.d4 {another comment} Nxd4 {you got it}'
```

My first solution was simply:

```
my_string = my_string.replace(my_string[my_string.find('{'):my_string.find('}')], '')
```

Unfortunately, this stripped just the first set of comments, like this:

```
'1.e4 } c5 2.Nf3 d6 3.d4 {another comment} Nxd4 {you got it}'
```

(the '}' that remained is not a problem, it can be deleted with:

```
my_string = my_string.replace('}', '')
```

So I tried to loop over the string:

```
for char in my_string:
    if char == '{':
        my_string = my_string.replace(my_string[my_string.find('{'):my_string.find('}')], '')
```

The very same thing happened, only the first set of comments was deleted.

Then I tried a while loop:

```
while my_string.find('{') != -1:
    my_string = my_string.replace(my_string[my_string.find('{'):my_string.find('}')], '')
```

And now I am stuck in an infinite loop...

Anyone knows how to solve this? I would accept a solution with lists too, which I could embed inside:

```
temp_list = list(my_string)
#solution with list manupulation
my_string = ''.join(temp_list)
```

Comment: What's your expected output? Why don't use `re.sub`? `re.sub(r'\{[^}]*}', '', my_string)`

Comment: Everything but comments inside { and }, these characters included. Following the example, I expect '1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 d6 3.d4  Nxd4 '

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions are perfect for this.

```
import re
re.sub(r'\s*{.*?}\s*', ' ', my_string)
# '1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 d6 3.d4 Nxd4 '
```

"replace any number of whitespace, an open curly, the least possible amount of anything at all (except newlines) followed by a closed curly and any amount of whitespace with a single space"

Comment: Nice use of `*?`, the ever-handy non-greedy collector. Short, sweet, and done.

Comment: Thank you Amadan, but it is not working, it is not deleting a single character. I didn't studied regular expressions yet so I don't know what to do. Maybe you missed something?

Comment: I did not; check [here](http://repl.it/fH5) (click Run). Maybe you missed something? Such as an assignment? (The above snippet will calculate the new string, but does not assign it to anything; and the old string is unchanged, of course, as Python's strings are immutable.)

Comment: Oooh the assignment! Yes, now it is working! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

As an additional remark to the other answer, if you are parsing a complex format (as PGN is, among many others), you should look into using a general-purpose parsing library, rather than writing your own ad-hoc parser. That will allow you to re-use shared logic that the library authors have written and debugged for you. Parsing is an extreme example of a use-case which has undergone a tremendous amount of research over the years, and by utilizing the proper library, you can benefit from this research in your own projects. [This list on the official Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing) suggests many possible options. [This blog post](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/python-parsers.html) offers a review of some popular options.

Comment: Thank you Ming, I will surely read your links. In fact, I even found a pgnparser package already on PyPI! I will try to study its code.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your attempts leave the the final `}` in place. This is because the `my_string.find('}')` returns the index of the `}`, but the `replace` function replaces everything *up to but not including the index*.

So, you need to increment the end index by 1:

```
my_string = my_string.replace(my_string[my_string.find('{'):my_string.find('}')+1], '')
```

As [@Amadan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29225165/1165522) suggests, I'd probably just use regular expressions for this exercise.